# Pandas expand rows from list data available in column

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, expand

I have a data frame like this in pandas:

```
 column1      column2
 [a,b,c]        1
 [d,e,f]        2
 [g,h,i]        3
```

## **Expected output:**

```
column1      column2
  a              1
  b              1
  c              1
  d              2
  e              2
  f              2
  g              3
  h              3
  i              3
```

How to process this data ?

Comment: What is `print (type(df.ix[0, 'column1'])` ?

Comment: print (type(df.ix[0, 'column1']) :--- is list

Answer (score 78):

#### `DataFrame.explode`

Since [**`pandas >= 0.25.0`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#series-explode-to-split-list-like-values-to-rows) we have the [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method for this, which expands a list to a row for each element and repeats the rest of the columns:

```
df.explode('column1').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
  column1  column2
0       a        1
1       b        1
2       c        1
3       d        2
4       e        2
5       f        2
6       g        3
7       h        3
8       i        3
```

---

Since [**`pandas >= 1.1.0`**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34932) we have the `ignore_index` argument, so we don't have to chain with `reset_index`:

```
df.explode('column1', ignore_index=True)
```

**Output**

```
  column1  column2
0       a        1
1       b        1
2       c        1
3       d        2
4       e        2
5       f        2
6       g        3
7       h        3
8       i        3
```

Comment: if you are using pandas < 0.25.0 i made a patch to make it running below
https://gist.github.com/BurakaKrishna/538cdad998247b95f9b2898015360a8e

Comment: I see yours is using lot of `for loops`, I would not advice people to use that approach, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe) are better vectorized alternatives for `pandas < 0.25.0` @ShivaRamaKrishna

Comment: Is there a good way to do this without lists as your index? For example, say I have to dateframes one with Timestamps with second accuracy, and another with only minute accuracy. I want to expand the one with minute accuracy by duplicating all values 60 times so I can merge them. I guess I can create a new index with a list of length 60 in each and do this explode method, but wondered if there is a more pandas way of doing this.

Comment: That looks like a [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html) from minute to second problem, not explode perse @topher217.

Comment: @Erfan perfect! Yes, I knew there had to be something. `resample` with `pad` or `bfill` looks like a great way to get this done. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

You can create `DataFrame` by its constructor and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
 df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.column1.tolist(), index=df.column2)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='column1')[['column1','column2']]
print (df2)

  column1  column2
0       a        1
1       b        1
2       c        1
3       d        2
4       e        2
5       f        2
6       g        3
7       h        3
8       i        3
```

If need change ordering by subset `[['column1','column2']]`, you can also omit first `reset_index`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.column1.tolist(), index=df.column2)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='column1')[['column1','column2']]
print (df2)
  column1  column2
0       a        1
1       b        1
2       c        1
3       d        2
4       e        2
5       f        2
6       g        3
7       h        3
8       i        3
```

Another solution [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) for creating `DataFrame` from first column, then create `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']],
                   'column2':[1,2,3]})


a = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.column1.tolist())
                .stack()
                .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                .rename('column1')

print (a)
0    a
0    b
0    c
1    d
1    e
1    f
2    g
2    h
2    i
Name: column1, dtype: object

print (df.drop('column1', axis=1)
         .join(a)
         .reset_index(drop=True)[['column1','column2']])

  column1  column2
0       a        1
1       b        1
2       c        1
3       d        2
4       e        2
5       f        2
6       g        3
7       h        3
8       i        3
```

Comment: In typical pandas fashion, this fails if the column consists of empty lists. Perfect.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is to use the `result_type='expand'` argument of the [`pandas.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function available since pandas 0.23. Answering [@splinter's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011511/pandas-expand-rows-from-list-data-available-in-column#comment88857222_39011596) this method can be generalized -- see below:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import arange

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'column1' : [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']],
    'column2': [1,2,3]}
)

pd.melt(
    df.join(
        df.apply(lambda row: row['column1'], axis=1, result_type='expand')
        ),
 value_vars=arange(df['column1'].shape[0]), value_name='column1', var_name='column2')[['column1','column2']]

# can be generalized 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'column1' : [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']],
    'column2': [1,2,3],
    'column3': [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]],
    'column4': [42,23,321],
    'column5': ['a','b','c']}
)

(pd.melt(
    df.join(
        df.apply(lambda row: row['column1'], axis=1, result_type='expand')
        ),
 value_vars=arange(df['column1'].shape[0]), value_name='column1', id_vars=df.columns[1:])
 .drop(columns=['variable'])[list(df.columns[:1]) + list(df.columns[1:])]
 .sort_values(by=['column1']))
```

**UPDATE** (for Jwely's comment):
if you have lists with varying length, you can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'column1' : [['a','b','c'],['d','f'],['g','h','i']],
    'column2': [1,2,3]}
)

longest = max(df['column1'].apply(lambda x: len(x)))

pd.melt(
    df.join(
        df.apply(lambda row: row['column1'] if len(row['column1']) >= longest else row['column1'] + [None] * (longest - len(row['column1'])), axis=1, result_type='expand')
    ),
 value_vars=arange(df['column1'].shape[0]), value_name='column1', var_name='column2').query("column1 == column1")[['column1','column2']]
```

Comment: I believe this solution requires every list in "column1" to be of the same length, 3 in this case.

Comment: I think the question was about lists with same length in the first column, but with slight modifications you can do different list lengths -- see my edit