# Pandas groupby and value counts for complex strings that have multiple occurrences

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a `df` like this:

```
    stringOfInterest        trend                  
0         C                    up
1         D                  down
2         E                  down
3         C,O                  up
4         C,P                  up
```

I want to plot this `df` as a bar graph using `pandas`. To obtain the proper grouped bar plots, I would like to group the data by the column `df["trend"]` and then count the occurrence of `df["stringOfInterest"]` for **each letter**. 
As can be seen, some of this strings contain multiple letters separated by a ",".

Using

```
df.groupby("trend").stringOfInterest.value_counts().unstack(0)
```

produces the expected result:

```
trend                  down    up
stringOfInterest                        
-                       7.0   8.0
C                       3.0  11.0
C,O                     NaN   2.0
C,P                     1.0   1.0
D                       1.0   2.0
E                      15.0  14.0
E,T                     1.0   NaN
```

However, I would like to count the occurrence of individual characters (C,E,D,...). 
On the original `df` this can be achieved like this:

```
s = df.stringOfInterest.str.split(",", expand = True).stack()
s.value_counts()
```

This typically generates something like this:

```
C     3
E     2
D     1
O     1
P     1
T     1
```

Unfortunately, this cannot be used here after the `groupby()` in combination with `unstack()`.

Maybe I am on the wrong track and some more elegant way would be preferred.

*To clarify the plotting: For each letter (stringOfInterest), there must be two bars indicating the number of "up" and "down" trend(s).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this answer here: [Pandas expand rows from list data available in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011511)

Is this something that would help you?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stringOfInterest': {0: 'C', 1: 'D', 2: 'E', 3: 'C,O', 4: 'C,P'},
     'trend': {0: 'up', 1: 'down', 2: 'down', 3: 'up', 4: 'up'}})


df2 = (pd.DataFrame(df.stringOfInterest.str.split(',').tolist(), index=df.trend)
        .stack()
        .reset_index()
        .groupby('trend')[0]
        .value_counts()
        .unstack()
      ).T

df2.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

---

**Another approach**

We could also zip the columns together and expand.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

data = [(x,i) for x,y in zip(df.trend,df.stringOfInterest.str.split(',')) for i in y]

pd.Series(Counter(data)).plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: The second is much more readable! Thanks for both. Any estimate on the performance?

Comment: @Fourier The 2nd I just came up with. However, I haven't confirmed they produce the result you are asking for.