# Expand lists in a dataframe, but with two columns containing the lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this (but much larger):

```
              begin        end   comp  p_n             next_d                        next_p
c_n   ml                                                                                                                                                   
1   1234 2013-09-02 2014-12-16  comp1  111 [20000, 25000, 50000]               [0.01, 0.01, 0.01]
    1235 2013-09-02 2014-12-16  comp2  222 [25000, 50000, 75000, 100000]       [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
2   1236 2013-09-02 2014-12-16  comp3  333 [5000, 10000, 15000, 170000, 25000] [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
    1237 2013-09-02 2014-12-16  comp4  444 [5000, 10000, 25000, 50000]         [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]
```

I need to expand both `next_d` and `next_p` which have the same list size for each particular row. I've tried various hints and answers, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011511/pandas-expand-rows-from-list-data-available-in-column) and [this](https://mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-split-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-rows-in-pandas-9849d8ff2401), but I need to expand two lists instead of one, and can't imagine how to apply this to my problem. Please help.

Comment: @yatu Oh, thanks, I've overlooked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use solution for one column for both `Series`, `concat` together and last `join`:

```
s1 = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('next_d').values.tolist(), 
                   index=df.index).stack().rename('next_d').reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
s2 = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('next_p').values.tolist(), 
                   index=df.index).stack().rename('next_p').reset_index(level=2, drop=True)

df = df.join(pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1))
print (df)
               begin         end   comp  p_n    next_d  next_p
c_n ml                                                        
1   1234  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp1  111   20000.0    0.01
    1234  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp1  111   25000.0    0.01
    1234  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp1  111   50000.0    0.01
    1235  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp2  222   25000.0    0.10
    1235  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp2  222   50000.0    0.10
    1235  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp2  222   75000.0    0.10
    1235  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp2  222  100000.0    0.10
2   1236  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp3  333    5000.0    0.10
    1236  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp3  333   10000.0    0.10
    1236  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp3  333   15000.0    0.10
    1236  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp3  333  170000.0    0.10
    1236  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp3  333   25000.0    0.10
    1237  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp4  444    5000.0    0.01
    1237  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp4  444   10000.0    0.01
    1237  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp4  444   25000.0    0.01
    1237  2013-09-02  2014-12-16  comp4  444   50000.0    0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

First define 2 functions, to be used later:

```
def createList(lst, lgth):
    return lst + [None] * (lgth - len(lst))

def createNames(name, lgth):
    return [ f'{name}_{i}' for i in range(1, lgth + 1) ]
```

Then compute max length of `next_d`:

```
maxLen = max(df.next_d.apply(len)); maxLen
```

Note that if the longest list in `next_d` is  e.g. 5 (as in your case),
then `next_d` will be replaced with just 5 new columns, the same applies to `next_p`.

Then compute the "extension array" (just the new columns):

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda row: createList(row['next_d'], maxLen) +
    createList(row['next_p'], maxLen), axis=1, result_type='expand')
df2.columns = createNames('next_d', maxLen) + createNames('next_p', maxLen)
```

And two last things to do are:

- drop both original columns,
- join the new columns.

  df = df.drop(columns=['next_d', 'next_p']).join(df2)

Now you can drop `df2`:

```
del df2
```

Of course, this is a **horizontal** expansion. After I read another answer,
I'm not sure which variant you want (horizontal or vertical).