# How to access the items in list from Dataframe against each index item?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Consider the table (Dataframe) below.

[image]

Need each item in the list against its index such as given below. What are the possible ways of doing this in python?

[image]

Anybody can tweak the question if it matches the context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas expand rows from list data available in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011511/pandas-expand-rows-from-list-data-available-in-column) Specifically the 2nd answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `pandas` library with the `explode` method. Here is how your code would look -

```
import pandas as pd

df = [["A", [1,2,3,4]],["B",[9,6,4]]]

df =  pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Index', 'Lists'])

print(df)

df = df.explode('Lists').reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Your output would be -

```
  Index         Lists
0     A  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1     B     [9, 6, 4]


  Index Lists
0     A     1
1     A     2
2     A     3
3     A     4
4     B     9
5     B     6
6     B     4
```